# How to proceed with troubleshooting access to Microservice?

Tags: azure, deployment, microservices, azure-aks

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/deploy-microservice-tutorial/deploy

At the end of the tutorial I attempted to navigate to "http://20.253.239.165/WeatherForecast" where 20.253.239.165 is the EXTERNAL-IP shown in the command prompt, but I get an error saying 20.253.239.165 took too long to respond.

I logged into my Azure Web Portal and verified that it is running there. I'm not sure why I wouldn't be able to access it though. Given that I don't see any instructions about whitelisting my IP nor do I see any ability (at first glance) to do so with the given resources I'm guessing that shouldn't be necessary.

Not sure how to proceed with troubleshooting at this point, nor do I know what additional information I should provide to help you guys help me. So... please help me help you help me. :)

[image]

EDIT: I see now that there is an error creating the container. Not quite sure what to do about it though:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looking at the describe output, it shows that there are no endpoints. which in turn means that the kubernetes service is misconfigured. labels dont match selectors (or deployment doesnt exist, or pods are not up, etc).

Comment: can you show your deployment manifest and `kubectl describe deploy xyz`?

Comment: I forgot I had it set to use Windows containers to try something with Service Fabric out. Unfortunately, switching back to Linux seems to have ruined the installation and I can't even get Docker Engine to start so now I'm dealing with that :/